# How to get iOS nativeURI from fileURI or fileURI from nativeURI

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap, cordova-plugin-camera

I am using the Cordova camera plugin to get a photo, however I need both the nativeURI and the fileURI. The nativeURI contains the EXIF location information, and the FileURI is a JPEG rather than a HEIF which cant be used in an img tag.

So I need to somehow get both.